# React native ImageChooserModule, not able to upload file with txt extention in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am using ImageChooserModule from react native

```
const { ImageChooserModule } = NativeModules;
```

When I am trying to upload images, pdf and doc it is working. But when I try to upload a txt file it shows isValid false.

```
const attachData = await ImageChooser.pickImage();
```

What is the correct useage to upload txt file.

Comment: Was able to fix it by sending correct mime type.  For text type, the mime type plain was not being checked